# Get redirect url from QtWebEnginePage

Tags: pyqt5

I have some code like below. In WebView are opening grant_request like this: "Do you want to grant permissions to app ?" and two buttons Cancel and Grant.
Button "Grant" generate redirect url.
How can I get redirect URL and close this form if clicked "Grant" and simply close this form if I click "Cancel" ?

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
import sys

class Main(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('name')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))
        web = QWebEngineView()
        web.load(QUrl("link_to_grant_req_page"))
        self.btn = QPushButton('Button', self)
        self.btn.resize(self.btn.sizeHint())
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn)
        lay.addWidget(web)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = Main()
main.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is closed: getting redirected link by context and return link by urlC